# Display certain posts from array of posts on html at intervals using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array of objects as input

```
var results=[
    {
        "title": "Sample Post",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>This is my brief content</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Here is the detail</p>"
        }
      },
    {
        "title": "Post 6",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief for Post 6</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description for Post 6</p>"
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "Post 7",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief for Post 7</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description for Post 7</p>"
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "Post 8",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief for Post 8</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description for Post 8</p>"
        }
      },
    {
        "title": "Post 1",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief for post 1</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description&nbsp;for post 1</p>"
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "Post 2",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief&nbsp;for post 2</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description&nbsp;for post 2</p>"
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "Post 222",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief&nbsp;for post 3</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description&nbsp;for post 3</p>"
        }
      },
    {
        "title": "Post 113",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief&nbsp;for post 3</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description&nbsp;for post 3</p>"
        }
      },
    {
        "title": "Post 223",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief&nbsp;for post 3</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description&nbsp;for post 3</p>"
        }
      }
];
```

I have to display only 3 posts at a time at interval of 3secs, suppose the input has 8 posts then the it should display first 3, then next 3 and then 2 and again the back to 3 posts so on.

I have tried this:

```
function showPosts(results, noOfPosts){

                    if(currentPost!=noOfPosts){
                        if(params.detail) {
                        var dtStr = "-";//format(dt);
                        $("#container").addClass("details");
                        $("#container").append('<div class="post"><div class="title">'+results[currentPost].title+'<i>'+dtStr+'</i></div><div class="content">'+results[currentPost].content.extended+'</div></div>');
                        countPost++;
                    } else {
                        $("#container").append('<div class="post"><span class="title">'+results[currentPost].title+'</span> - '+results[currentPost].content.brief+'</div>');
                        countPost++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        countPost=0;
                        $("#container").removeClass("class");


                }

                setInterval(function(){
                    showPosts(results, noOfPosts)
                },3000)
```

Comment: So..what is the issue?

Comment: It prints only 1st 3 posts. when ' noOfPosts=3'

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var results=[
    {
        "title": "Sample Post",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>This is my brief content</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Here is the detail</p>"
        }
      },
    {
        "title": "Post 6",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief for Post 6</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description for Post 6</p>"
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "Post 7",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief for Post 7</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description for Post 7</p>"
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "Post 8",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief for Post 8</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description for Post 8</p>"
        }
      },
    {
        "title": "Post 1",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief for post 1</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description&nbsp;for post 1</p>"
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "Post 2",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief&nbsp;for post 2</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description&nbsp;for post 2</p>"
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "Post 222",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief&nbsp;for post 3</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description&nbsp;for post 3</p>"
        }
      },
    {
        "title": "Post 113",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief&nbsp;for post 3</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description&nbsp;for post 3</p>"
        }
      },
    {
        "title": "Post 223",
        "content": {
          "brief": "<p>Brief&nbsp;for post 3</p>",
          "extended": "<p>Full description&nbsp;for post 3</p>"
        }
      }
];
var currentPost = 0;
var noOfPosts = 3;
var startIndex=0;
var endIndex= noOfPosts+startIndex-1;
function showPosts(results, noOfPosts){
        $("#container").innerHTML="";
    $("#container").addClass("details");
    for(var i=startIndex;i<endIndex+1;i++){     
        $("#container").append('<div class="post"><div class="title">'+results[i].title+'</div><div class="content">'+results[i].content.extended+'</div></div>');

    }
}

setInterval(function(){
    showPosts(results, noOfPosts);
    startIndex =(endIndex==(results.length-1))?0:endIndex+1;
    endIndex =((noOfPosts+startIndex)>results.length)? endIndex = results.length-1 :noOfPosts+startIndex-1;

},3000);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>


</body>
</html>
```